# aws policy for read/write to a file within a bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have the following s3 structure:

bucket name: test-bucket

file: test.json

And I have the following aws policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this policy is attached to a user with access key 123.

When I try to put or get the test.json in the test-bucket using the sdk as this:

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("123", "secretKeyId");
s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                        .withRegion("US-EAST-1")
                        .build();
s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("test-bucket", "test.json", file));
```

This will give the access deny problem.

If I change the policy's resource to

```
 "Resource": "*"
```

then it will work. I just want to make sure the resource I put is in correct format. What went wrong?

Comment: Typo: `ListBucekt` -> `ListBucket`

Comment: @Jeremy Oh that's the typo during copy-paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let amazon know that beside your bucket you also want to access content of your bucket.

So change resource from:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket"
```

To something like:

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket",
    "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
]
```